# how to improve the performance of function which takes almost 1 second in loading time (asp.net mvc 3)

Tags: performance, asp.net-mvc-3, loading, profiler

I did a profile tracing to check what functions are taking long times , One of the method takes near 1 second and is called 10+ times and i guess it should be a candidate for review. I have included the method, Can anyone tell me how can it possible be improved.

```
 [NonAction]
    private ProductModel.ProductMiscModel PrepareProductMiscModel(Product product)
    {
        if (product == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException("product");

        var model = new ProductModel.ProductMiscModel();
        var productVariants = _productService.GetProductVariantsByProductId(product.Id);
        var getManufactureImage = _manufacturerService.GetProductManufacturersByProductId(product.Id)
           .Select(x =>
           {
               var m = x.Manufacturer.ToModel();
               m.PictureModel.ImageUrl = _pictureService.GetPictureUrl(x.Manufacturer.PictureId, _mediaSetting.ManufacturerThumbPictureSize, true);
               m.PictureModel.Title = string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("Media.Manufacturer.ImageLinkTitleFormat"), m.Name);
               m.PictureModel.AlternateText = string.Format(_localizationService.GetResource("Media.Manufacturer.ImageAlternateTextFormat"), m.Name);
               return m;
           })
           .ToList();
        model.manufactureName = getManufactureImage;
        switch (productVariants.Count)
        {
            case 0:
                {
                    //var productVariant = productVariants[0];
                    model.Sku = null;
                    model.ShowSku = false;
                   // model.attributeName = 0;
                } break;
            case 1:
                //only one variant
                {               var productVariant = productVariants[0];
                                model.Sku = productVariant.Sku; //null;
                                model.ShowSku = true;
                               // model.attributeName = _productAttributeService.GetProductVariantAttributesByProductVariantId(productVariant.Id);
                                model.productSpecification = _specificationAttributeService.GetProductSpecificationAttributesByProductId(productVariant.Product.Id);
                }
                break;

        }

        return model;
    }
```

_manufactureService.GetProductManufactureByProductId

```
public virtual IList<ProductManufacturer> GetProductManufacturersByProductId(int productId, bool showHidden = false)
    {
        if (productId == 0)
            return new List<ProductManufacturer>();

        string key = string.Format(PRODUCTMANUFACTURERS_ALLBYPRODUCTID_KEY, showHidden, productId);
        return _cacheManager.Get(key, () =>
                                          {
                                              var query = from pm in _productManufacturerRepository.Table
                                                          join m in _manufacturerRepository.Table on
                                                              pm.ManufacturerId equals m.Id
                                                          where pm.ProductId == productId &&
                                                                !m.Deleted &&
                                                                (showHidden || m.Published)
                                                          orderby pm.DisplayOrder
                                                          select pm;
                                              var productManufacturers = query.ToList();
                                              return productManufacturers;
                                          });
    }
```

Comment: You make three calls to "services". What are these services? Are they SQL database, Web Services?

Comment: Services is the  Business Access Layer (BAL) where business logic, validations or calculations related with the data is performed

Comment: Understood,but they're retrieving data?Is the method with which they are retrieving the slow part?If each one is taking 250ms...

Comment: updated the question with one of the list method in Manufacture Service

Comment: That doesn't suggest it would be slow, unless the cache fail is expensive.Does it still take a second the next time you call it?

Comment: no the second time is bit faster but how can i improve at first instance , is there any way i can improve the service methods , thats how i talking to the database using Linq , is LINQ is the culprit behind the lag

Comment: If this is the first database hit, then it could be. If you're using Entity Framework code first, then the first time it hits the tables can be a little slower than subsequent calls,something I'm still learning about in my current app.I would follow the other suggestion,StopWatch,then if you find it to be the culprit,do some further research there.

Comment: Yep I am looking into it , and its first code

Answer (score 1):

Use `StopWatch` in the method to determine which part it is that takes long time.

you might want to include the picture url in the original list instead of traversing each item and call `_pictureService.GetPictureUrl`.